# Power BI Embedded - Embedding Tiles

Tags: c#, .net, azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to embed a report that I did on Power BI desktop in a mobile app. The API only shows that I can embed the whole report not a page/tile.

I searched again and I found this [thread](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-integrate-tile-code/). However, it seems like Power BI Embedded and Power BI (online) are 2 different products and they have different APIs.

Example - Getting reports created on Power BI desktop and published online:

1- Power BI Online API

```
GET https://api.powerbi.com/beta/myorg/Dashboards
```

2- Power BI Embedded API

```
https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/collections/{collection}/workspaces/{workspaceID}/reports
```

Can you please explain the difference? Also, how can I embed a tile in Power BI embedded? If I can't do that can I do it with Power BI Online (if yes, can you suggest a step by step guide please)?

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely do it with "Power BI Online".

Here is a walk through : [link](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-integrate-tile/)

Here is source on Github : [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp/tree/master/samples/webforms/integrate-tile-web-app)

This whole scenario is confusing I think mostly because of the product naming.  To further the confusion the root of that github project states that it is for PowerBI Embedded however these are examples I used before power bi embedded existed and if you look at the [project packages](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp/blob/master/samples/webforms/integrate-tile-web-app/PBIWebApp/packages.config) file for the tile embedded it is not using any of the NEW power bi embedded packages.  So I am not sure if this means that this will also work with power bi embedded, by using a similar url structure.

As far as differences, power bi embedded is an azure service offering.  One of the more prominent differences is in the power bi online licensing.  Power BI embedded is NOT TIED to an individual users AAD account, you request the report by using the ACCESS KEY from the PowerBI Embedded blade in azure.  With the Power BI Service each user you would like to view the report must have a power bi license and the particular report must be shared to them.  So when your web app is requesting a specific report it is doing it on the behalf of the logged in user.  There are many more differences between the 2 offerings based on how you work with the APIs, to me the difference I described is a major factor in determining which service to use based on what you are trying to accomplish with your web app integration.

More info: [What is Power BI Embedded](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/power-bi-embedded-what-is-power-bi-embedded/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I successfully embedded a tile in Android webview. However, there is no Focus mode. Do you know anything about that?